# How to Start Ubuntu in TTY without GUI as VB Guest?

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox 5. 
The graphics is limited in VirtualBox so I would just have textual appearance in TTYs.
I would like to access TTYs of Ubuntu in VB5.

My problem is that I cannot press the keyboard combination in my OS X host GUI, which I normally do in Linux environments.

---

How can you access only TTYs of Ubuntu 14.04 in VB5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following key combination will get you to a TTY of a running Ubuntu Virtual Box:

<kbd>Host Key</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> ... <kbd>F7</kbd>

In case you do not need a graphical user interface at all consider to install Ubuntu server edition to the virtual machine.

Comment: I just need Matlab and its textual outputs - errors and warnings. I can easily transfer the outputs elsewhere for graphical inspection. So I think the server could be a good choice but I have not installed Matlab before in a server.

Comment: Left CMD + fn + f1..f11. You are rigth!

Answer (score 0):

Your VirtualBox run on a Linux Host or a Windows one? if its on Windows you can download a tool like putty and connect with ssh protocol to your virtual machine.
If its on Linux, so open a terminal you need to connect also with ssh if it doesnt work try to install ssh server and client with sudo apt-get install openssh-client

Comment: My VB runs in OS X.